# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, servlets, tomcat7

I am new to eclipse and tomcat. I am creating a servlet that takes an image and save it in a databse.
I am using Jre 1.6 and tomcat 7. For this i used custom libraries :

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
```

Now i am having this error while deploying my project:

```
10 Jun, 2013 6:34:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/BIOMetric2]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)    

etc..
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used @MultipartConfig and this is working fine now. I used this code.
...

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
```

...

```
Part filePart = request.getPart("img");
String imageName = filePart.getName(); 
InputStream in = filePart.getInputStream();
```

....